# Azure AD OAuth 2.0 Auth Code Token Exchange using cert

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

The docs for the OAuth2 auth code to token exchange show making a request using client_id and client_secret. However is there a way to do this using cert based auth for the azure app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can acquire tokens using a certificate instead of using client secret as well. It's covered as part of Client Credentials Grant.

**Azure AD V1 Endpoint**

Here is a detailed code sample - It makes use of a self signed certificate and uses Azure AD V1 endpoint

[Authenticating to Azure AD in daemon apps with certificates](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-certificate-credential#authenticating-to-azure-ad-in-daemon-apps-with-certificates)

```
certCred = new ClientAssertionCertificate(clientId, cert);
result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(todoListResourceId, certCred);
```

In case you're looking to make direct REST based calls (not using ADAL Library) here's a sample. You can read more details on each of the parameters here on Microsoft Docs:

[Access token request with a certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#second-case-access-token-request-with-a-certificate)

```
POST /<tenant_id>/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

resource=https%3A%2F%contoso.onmicrosoft.com%2Ffc7664b4-cdd6-43e1-9365-c2e1c4e1b3bf&client_id=97e0a5b7-d745-40b6-94fe-5f77d35c6e05&client_assertion_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Aclient-assertion-type%3Ajwt-bearer&client_assertion=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Imd4OHRHeXN5amNScUtqRlBuZDdSRnd2d1pJMCJ9.eyJ{a lot of characters here}M8U3bSUKKJDEg&grant_type=client_credentials
```

**Azure AD V2 Endpoint**

Using MSAL.NET Library you can do it like this. Both client secret and Certificate Credentials variations are shown here. (Certificate is covered in the else case)

More details available here - [Client credential flows in MSAL.NET](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-credential-flows#client-credential-flows-in-msalnet)

```
// Even if this is a console application here, a daemon application is a confidential client application
IConfidentialClientApplication app;

#if !VariationWithCertificateCredentials
app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(config.ClientId)
           .WithTenantId("{tenantID}")
           .WithClientSecret(config.ClientSecret)
           .Build();
#else
// Building the client credentials from a certificate
X509Certificate2 certificate = ReadCertificate(config.CertificateName);
app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(config.ClientId)
    .WithTenantId("{tenantID}")
    .WithCertificate(certificate)
    .Build();
#endif

// With client credentials flows the scopes is ALWAYS of the shape "resource/.default", as the
// application permissions need to be set statically (in the portal or by PowerShell), and then granted by
// a tenant administrator
string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

AuthenticationResult result = null;
try
{
 result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                   .ExecuteAsync();
}
catch(MsalServiceException ex)
{
 // Case when ex.Message contains:
 // AADSTS70011 Invalid scope. The scope has to be of the form "https://resourceUrl/.default"
 // Mitigation: change the scope to be as expected
}
```

Again in case you're interested in making direct REST based calss (not using MSAL Library) here's a sample.You can read more details on each of the parameters here on Microsoft Docs:

[Access token request with a certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#second-case-access-token-request-with-a-certificate)

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1               // Line breaks for clarity
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_id=97e0a5b7-d745-40b6-94fe-5f77d35c6e05
&client_assertion_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Aclient-assertion-type%3Ajwt-bearer
&client_assertion=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Imd4OHRHeXN5amNScUtqRlBuZDdSRnd2d1pJMCJ9.eyJ{a lot of characters here}M8U3bSUKKJDEg
&grant_type=client_credentials
```