# AAD Sharepoint Api

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I have a working Rest API which is using a Client Certificate to access SharePoint (Cloud).
I registered my Rest API with App Permissions in AAD and would like to protect the Rest API.
Therefore I need to register a second Application, which will be a ERP-Software that is supposed to authenticate itself with a Client Secret and has the permission to access the Rest API. I can only use Http Requests in the ERP Software and for now I can access the currently not protected Rest API to access and create SharePoint Data.
Can somebody give an advice how to setup the protection for the Rest Api in AAD and how I can obtain the OAuth Token only via Http Requests and a Client Certificate (no User interaction) from my ERP-Software?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the provided references  and see if it is the flow that is required in your case :

You can acquire tokens using a certificate instead of using client secret as well. You can check OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant  which is commonly used for server-to-server interactions that must run in the background, without immediate interaction with a user
Below is the Sample request shown in reference using certificate

**Access token request with a certificate**

Referred from [second-case-access-token-request-with-a-certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#second-case-access-token-request-with-a-certificate)

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1               // Line breaks for clarity
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_id=97e0a5b7-d745-40b6-94fe-5f77d35c6e05
&client_assertion_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Aclient-assertion-type%3Ajwt-bearer
&client_assertion=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Imd4OHRHeXN5amNScUtqRlBuZDdSRnd2d1pJMCJ9.eyJ{a lot of characters here}M8U3bSUKKJDEg
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

According to  [certificate based changes | github](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/2-Call-OwnApi#daemon-applications-can-use-two-forms-of-secrets-to-authenticate-themselves-with-azure-ad) , make the changes in manifest to allow application type and expose the api and grant permissions for the required scopes

Also check  [azuread-oauth-2.0 auth code token exchange using cert-SO
Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56398319/azure-ad-oauth-2-0-auth-code-token-exchange-using-cert)